# Is there a default way to normalize a string into a valid symbol?

Tags: clojure, normalization

I'm writing a macro that transform a keyword into a symbol This symbol will be used on a `(def ~symbol ...)` There is a "default" way to normalize `:foo.bar/quoo` to a valid symbol? `(symbol (namespace kw) (name kw))`?

Comment: Your suggestion is the best way I can think of.

Answer (score 5):

Since Clojure 1.10 you can also use `symbol` directly with keywords, even namespaced ones:

```
user> (symbol :plain-kw)
plain-kw
user> (type (symbol :plain-kw))
clojure.lang.Symbol
user> (symbol :namespaced/kw)
namespaced/kw
user> (type (symbol :namespaced/kw))
clojure.lang.Symbol
```